# How to download ebooks from Kindle to PC?

Tags: kindle, download

I'm am trying to download some Kindle eBooks that I have bought to my laptop. I tried connecting my Kindle to my PC via USB and then try to access the files from there, but I can't find the files that actually contain the book. I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong, or if this just isn't possible. How can I download eBooks from my Kindle to my PC?

---

<sup>The Kindle is a Kindle Paperwhite and the laptop is an Ubuntu. Not sure if that matters, though.</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Calibre, on the other hand allows one to edit epub books, convert between file types and generally maintain your ebook library on your computer. You can then send them to your various readers. Some of those features require removal of DRM to do but there are many public domain ebooks.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The screenshot is from my iMac but the principal is the same in Ubuntu. The azw3 files are actual book files. Older ones may have been .mobi files. Just highlight the ones you want and copy (control c) and paste (control v) where you want them. You can also delete them if you wish but I would leave any of the other files in each folder as they contain useful information about the book and your history with it such as indexes, dictionary lookups etc.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Calibre, switch to your "Device":

[image: Device library]

Select the books that are not in your Calibre library (i.e., the ones without the check mark), right-click and then click "Add books to library":

[image: Click "Add books to library"]

That's particularly useful if you have some books on Kindle that you didn't have in your library, thus you don't have to check which ones are missing, neither copy them manually.

Answer (score 0):

with downloading the kindle software from Amazon you tell Amazon that there is one more device to distribute your ebooks to. You can have some more devices connected to your account: iPad, Smartphone etc.
Then the downloading will be very easy.
Maybe you will need a Windows partition.

Answer (score 0):

The current version of the kindle cloud reader stores books to a WebSQL Database, which is basically a sqlite file on hard disk.
Unfortunately the ebooks are stored in a proprietary, obfuscated format, thus just locating the file doesn't help much.

One possibility to convert this to an open/usable format is this nodejs script: https://github.com/d10r/kindle-fetch

Answer (score -2):

I've been using Calibre Library for windows as well as Ubuntu and just totally love it, [Calibre for Ubuntu](http://calibre-ebook.com/download_linux)

Comment: Can you expand your answer with some specifics on how the OP can solve his problem (moving ebooks from Kindle to PC) using Calibre?

Comment: I second Anthon's comment.  I know how to use Calibre, but that depends on getting the books off of the Kindle in the first place.  I've looked around the file system of my Kindle, and it's not clear what to take there.

Comment: Calibre can synchronize your library with Kindle, can't it do it vice-versa?